# How can I render a depth map provided from ARCore using sceneview?

Tags: kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneview

I used ARCores depth API master lab for the foundation, BoxRenderer, DepthData, depthRenderer and their shaders. All the data seems to work, but since they use openCL for rendering im having trouble porting it to Sceneview, I honestly dont know where to start. Does anyone have any pointers and point me in the right direction?

Added all the needed classes for the rendering, I was able to get all of the raw data, but wasnt able to display anything inside the AR viewport